# reaver WPS transaction failed on BT5

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wps

I have installed backtrack 5 gnome x86 on my Acer Aspire One (2gb RAM), and I'm trying to brute force my own wifi network using reaver, but I'm getting every time again an error, and it's trying all the time the same pin.

This is my reaver command (monitor mode was enabled on mon0)

```
reaver -i mon0 -b 72:2B:C1:CB:EA:CC -vv
```

and this is my output

```
Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner   <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[+] Waiting for beacon from *bssid*
[+] Switching mon0 to channel 5
[+] Associated with *bssid* (ESSID: *ssid*)
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[!] WARNING: Receive timeout occurred
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x02), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Nothing done, nothing to save.
[+] 0.00% complete @ 2015-10-21 19:13:29 (0 seconds/pin)
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
[+] Received WSC NACK
[+] Sending WSC NACK
[!] WPS transaction failed (code: 0x04), re-trying last pin
[+] Trying pin 12345670
[+] Sending EAPOL START request
[+] Received identity request
[+] Sending identity response
[+] Received M1 message
[+] Sending M2 message
^C
[+] Nothing done, nothing to save.
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong or what these errors actually mean?

I found something here http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/issues/detail?id=630#c41

They say I have to downgrade libpcap but the download link they give is dead

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the file in `/usr/local/etc/reaver/<mac>.wpc`?
There's a possibility that it is corrupt.

Here is the Libpcap download link:http://launchpadlibrarian.net/142508639/libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_i386.deb

I assume this is the one you want ^^

Source: https://gitlab.com/billhibadb/reaver-wps/issues/520